# Excel 2013: Why is automatic numbering not working for me?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Excel 2013: Why is automatic numbering not working for me ?

I click OK:

[image: IMG:]

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

According to your image, you don't have a first value. You want the series to have a step of 87, but Excel doesn't know what is the starting value. Specify the start value by selecting a cell that contains it.

If your starting value is the cell with 86, you need to select it. Then enter your step. But note that a step of 87 will mean 86+87. If you want to go from 86 to 87, then your step should be 1.